# Accent aigu sur le « e » de « demain »

Tags: prononciation, orthographe, diacritiques

Voici les règles de placement d'accent aigu, selon la Nouvelle Grammaire du Français, de Delatour *et al.*

[image]

La syllabe **de** du mot **demain** n'est pas suivie d'un double consonne ou d'un **-x** et n'est pas terminée par **-r**, **-z**, **-d**, **-f**. Pourquoi n'est-elle pas accentuée ?

Comment: Je réponds à votre question: "quelles sont les prononciations de la lettre 'e' ?" au bas de cette page...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Les règles a, b, c citées représentent des contraintes sur l'accent aigu.

Cela ne veut pas dire qu'il faut mettre un accent aigu sur tout autre « e », mais sur tout autre « e » qui se prononce [e] (comme dans « march**é** »).

C'est-à-dire que si tu entends [e], tu écris « é », et vice versa, sauf si cet « e » se trouve dans l'un de ces contextes où l'accentuation est impossible.

Tu as donc raison quand tu observes que le contexte de « demain » ne correspond pas à ces règles : mais sa première syllabe ne se prononce pas [e]. L'accent aigu n'a donc aucune justification.

Comment: Malgré tout, le premier E de **erreur**, sauf erreur de ma part, ne se prononce pas [e]. Peut-être localement, cependant... Je ne suis pas familier du tout avec cette prononciation, mais peut-être existe-t-elle. Elle serait néanmoins plutôt l'exception que la règle.

Comment: @Montéedelait True. Three observations: (1) I notice that on WordReference, the pronunciation examples for each of those words has more of an [e] for France and more of an [ɛ] for Québec (e.g. [*erreur*](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/erreur)). (2) A vowel preceding an [ʁ] would sound less front and high as well. (3) However, even some of their exemples are listed as containing [ɛ] on WordReference, suggesting that perhaps they didn't mean that these are all unaccented [e] but that an [e] would be unaccented in such cases. What do you think?

Comment: Quelles sont les prononciations possibles de la lettre "e"?

Comment: @LukeSawczak Your third observation might well be what explains the whole thing best. Your #2 seems legit to me, but then, I am so Québécois (or French-Canadian, c'est selon) that I come to doubt myself on it, because of the link you provided in your first comment, that show me a reality different than the one I've been used to since I was born. But you made three very good points overall. Thanks.

Comment: @BrunoSchiavo [e] [(ici)](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyelle_mi-ferm%C3%A9e_ant%C3%A9rieure_non_arrondie) — [ɛ] [(ici)](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyelle_mi-ouverte_ant%C3%A9rieure_non_arrondie) — [ə] [(ici)](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyelle_moyenne_centrale) — Parfois, plus ou moins localement selon le mot: [ø] [(ici)](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyelle_mi-ferm%C3%A9e_ant%C3%A9rieure_arrondie) ou [œ] [(ici)](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyelle_mi-ouverte_ant%C3%A9rieure_arrondie) — de nombreux cas aussi de [E muets](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_caduc).

Comment: Je suis halluciné par le plébiscite de ce post qui ne répond pas à la question: Personne n'approuve mon travail, tandis que notre ami italien s'imagine qu'on dit "démain" et donc il se demande pourquoi il n'y a pas d'accent sur le "e". Vous ne répondez pas à sa question et on vous applaudit! StackExchange est un endroit parfois bien mystérieux...

Answer (score 5):

Haha !

A/ Problème de logique : Noter que les règles que tu cites correspondent toutes à des cas systématiques répondant à : *il n'y a **pas***.
=> Ne disent en aucun cas là où il devrait y en avoir. => Ne disent pas qu'il en *faudrait* un sur demain.

B/... Haha... mais fondamentalement... ce n'est pas absurde du tout! Il **pourrait** effectivement y en avoir un... sur *demain* et sur d'autres du même tabac (*celui, retiré*...) et d'ailleurs... **il y en avait bien un**!... Chez les Périgourdins (entre autres) qui prononçaient effectivement *c**é**lui, d**é**main, r**é**tiré...*

[(Lire *Une Politique de la langue*
De Michel de Certeau, Dominique Julia, Jacques Revel)](https://books.google.fr/books?id=KHfZAwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=Une%20politique%20de%20la%20langue&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwikjduvkoTeAhVOTBoKHbU1CRMQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=Une%20politique%20de%20la%20langue&f=false)

Answer (score 2):

Bonjour,

La voyelle "e" en français est un peu compliquée, car elle peut avoir 4 prononciations, que la phonétique internationale a référencées, mais dont nous n'avons pas hélas ici les symboles sous la main, nous pouvons donc les redéfinir avec des lettres standard:

```
. [ë] : feu, nœud, bleu [fë], [në], [blë] (e fermé)
. [e] : fleur, beurre, sœur  [fler], [ber], [ser] (e ouvert)
. [è] : fer, bête, stèle [fèr], [bèt], [stèl]
. [é] : blé, nez, pied [blé], [né], [pié]
```

Nous appliquerons la même logique du tréma(¨) à la fermeture de la voyelle "o", qui peut se prononcer de 2 manières:

```
. [ö] : taule, rôle, beau [töl], [röl], [bö] (o fermé)
. [o] : colle, bol, botte [col], [bol], [bot] (o ouvert)
```

De même nous noterons les voyelles nasales `in, an, on` par les lettres suivantes:

```
[î], [â], [ô] : pain [pî], paon [pâ], pont [pô]
```

A ce sujet, ajoutons que la voyelle "e" présente une autre difficulté, car la graphie **"en"** est assez compliquée, puisqu'elle peut se prononcer soit `[î]`, soit `[â]`, soit `[èn]` :

p**en**tagone `[pîtagön]`, p**en**tecôte `[pâtcöt]`, Le P**en** `[lëpèn]`

Pour répondre à votre question, il se trouve tout simplement que le mot `demain` se prononce avec le `[ë]` défini ci-dessus: `[dëmî]`. Il n'y a donc aucune raison de mettre un accent sur le e, même s'il est fréquent d'entendre les Italiens ou les Espagnols dire `[démî]`, ce que ne fait aucun Français.

Je dois ajouter que je suis abasourdi par la grammaire dont vous produisez un extrait, car elle semble ignorer la différence entre `[é]` et `[è]`, ce qui, venant d'un supposé grammairien, est assez surprenant: Il présente le symbole `[e]` comme l'équivalent de ce que nous avons noté `[é]`, et il l'applique ensuite à des mots pour lesquels sa prononciation n'a pas cours!

En effet, on ne dit pas `[érer]` mais `[èrer]` (erreur), de même pour tous les exemples qu'il cite: `[èfor]`(effort), `[èfasé]` (effacer) etc... Méfiez-vous donc, vous avez en main une grammaire que l'on peut qualifier de douteuse.

Comment: Je pense c'est une grammaire pour le FLE.

Comment: Justement, vous ne m'avez pas compris: ce n'est pas la notation que je conteste, mais les mots auxquels il applique cette notation, et auxquels elle ne s'applique pas.

Comment: Diantre, je prononce [érer], [éfor] et [éfasé] ... mais ([mé]) aussi poulet et lait avec des [é]... surement l'accent du sud, ça.

Comment: *Demain* ne se prononce pas avec un [ë] mais avec [ə]. Et *ain* se prononce [ɛ̃]. À ma connaissance le son [î] n'existe pas en français, etc...   Et ce qui est écrit dans le livre de grammaire cité dans la question est tout à fait exact. La voyelle [e] (je vous rappelle que le signes notés entre crochets se référent toujours à la notation de l'API), ne s'écrit pas toujours -é (ici transcription, orthographique)  est tout à fait exact.